# New SSL certificate not being trusted on all clients

Tags: tls

I just got an old SSL cert renewed by GoDaddy.  It works fine on most clients I've seen.  However on some of our more restricted computers there is an issue.  These computers have GPO's set to block access to all websites that are not owned by us.  When they try to navigate to a site with this new SSL cert, they show a certificate error.  Instead of showing all 3 certs, they show ours, and the intermediate GoDaddy cert.

However, upon logging into a more privledged account that does not have the web restrictions, the site loads just fine.  Then switching back to the restricted account...  It begins to work to, and lists all 3 certs in the chain...

I'm a bit out of my depth here,  Does any one have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: If you're looking for good answers to this question, I'd recommend providing a bit more information.  1) what error exactly is being shown on the clients that aren't working 2) how do the GPOs implement the block on non-company owned sites (i.e. do they look at the CN of the cert, do they look at some other field in the cert etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Windows Update. I think you might have missed one of the regular Microsoft root certificate program updates.

## Edit: Windows downloads CAs on demand, too

Windows has a [mechanism that will check and add new CAs to the trust store upon contact.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc734018(WS.10).aspx)

Combined with the limitations on web access I imagine this might be responsible for the admin/nonadmin difference.

Comment: That would be an awesome solution, If i didnt have 1000 laptops out in the field.  I have no management into them (before my time).  I'm mostly trying to figure out what is going on, because I dont understand how logging in as an admin fixes the problem for all accounts.

Comment: Okay. Can you deploy the root CA certs via GPO?

Comment: Nope,  these laptops are completly out of my control.  All over the world.  I know im in a bad situation...  I'm just trying to understand what is causing it at this point.